# Fade in and fade out dynamic divs

Tags: jquery, css

i've been working on a school project for my final exam for some days now, and this thing happened:
My div(s) keep fading in and out and after a while they stop, i've come with this jquery so far

Here i create some variables to have the div disappear when it reaches the fixed height (the divs are sticky as you can see in the css so it wont work by taking the height whenever i want)

```
$('.processor').each(function(){
$counter += 1;
fromTop[$counter] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
$counter = 0;
$('.processor').each(function(){
    $counter += 1;
    if($(window).scrollTop() > fromTop[$counter])
    {
        $(this).fadeTo(500,0);   
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() > fromTop[$counter-1])  //Check if the scroll is enought to make the other div appear
    {
        $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    }
 });
 });
```

--- css ---

```
.processor{
width:65%;
height:70%;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(179, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(95, 0, 0, 0.75));;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:3px;
top: 18%;
position:sticky;
margin-bottom:250px;
}
```

Comment: It's because you fire off your animation everytime the scroll event is launched (it can be fired multiple times during one scroll) - you either want to throttle the scroll event so it only fires once after it stops or stop the animation before restarting it

Comment: Umh i'm not much of an expert so I don't really know where to start to fix in your way, could you help me out or redirect me to somewhere where they explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like use a `setTimeout` to delay firing your animation until the scrolling stops:

```js
var $window = $(window), // cache this for better performance
    timeoutVar ; // declare timeoutVar 

$window.scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutVar);  // clear timeout so it doesn't fire fade function
  
  timeoutVar = setTimeout(fade, 100); // run the fade function in 100ms (will only run if scrolling has stopped)
});


function fade() {
  $('.processor').each(function(index, item) {   // get your passed in items so you can use them
    var $item = $(item); // this is just the proper way of doing $(this);
    
    if ($window.scrollTop() > fromTop[index + 1]) {  // just use the index - instead of the counter (they pretty much do the same thing)
      $item.fadeOut(500);  // you may as well use fade in and fadeout
    } else {
      $item.fadeIn(500);  // you may as well use fade in and fadeout
    }
    
    // seems a bit weird you fade the same thing based on something else
    if ($window.scrollTop() > fromTop[index]) //Check if the scroll is enought to make the other div appear
    {
      $item.fadeIn(500);  // you may as well use fade in and fadeout
    }
  });
}
```

**Update as per comments**

ok as you need to start animating immediately, I would just stop the existing animation

```js
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  fade());
});


function fade() {
  $('.processor').each(function(index, item) { // get your passed in items so you can use them
      var $item = $(item); // this is just the proper way of doing $(this);

      // this if is if the current item is scrolled into view and there is no next item or the scroll is below the next item
      if ($window.scrollTop() > fromTop[index] && (typeof fromTop[index + 1] === 'undefined' || $window.scrollTop() < fromTop[index + 1])) {
        $item.stop().fadeIn(500); // you may as well use fade in and fadeout -- add stop() to stop excisting animatiohn
      } else {
        $item.stop().fadeOut(500); // you may as well use fade in and fadeout
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get how it could work, the function fade() isn't inside the $window.scroll so how does it launch the function? Either way, thanks for the time but i really need the fade to happen while scrolling and not when it stops

Comment: setTimeout(fade, 100) <- the fade function is called here

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Ok so, i do have the result i want, the only problem now is that the same div keeps appearing and disappearing even if i scrolled all the way down, any help with that?

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, the comment you made on my appearing for the other div made me actually think (god was that stupid), I had to check if the div was between the two heights, sorry for the trouble and having wasted your time to someone so stupid as me thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Neyco See edit - I changed it so your animation should run immediately and stop any existing.  I also changed the if around so it should only animate once per thing

Comment: Got it to work, thanks a lot for helping me out with some parts of logic that I couldn't manage to get, i got the exact result i wanted

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will add animations to the queue, which can lead to multiple animations playing out after a while (I remember seeing this a while ago on multiple websites with mouseOver animations).

The problem is that you do want to check every time the window scrolls, but ofcourse as a user scrolls that event is fired multiple times. If you know that the animation you set up in the .scroll function is final, you can explicitly set the animation queue to one, like so:

```
if ($(this).queue().length > 1) $(this).queue() = 1; //do this before applying fadeTo
```

This will allow the queue to finish its current animation and then run the one you want, and end there. So after scrolling a bunch of times, the div will only go through 2 animations at most.